# Correlated value from min query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the correlated value in a table from a mysql query which looks like:

```
 select min(c), d 
 from example
```

table `example` looks like:

```
 c     |  d
 ----------------
'1,99',  '30,99'
'5,99',  '8,46'
'9,99',  '14,99'
'11,79', '17,24'
'12,99', '19,44'
'15,99', '22,44'
'22,49', '34,48'
```

Given result:

```
1,99 & 34,48
```

Expected result:

```
1,99 & 30,99
```

What I want is the correlated value from the min(c) in this case '30,99'. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a sub query:

```
SELECT * FROM example 
WHERE c = (SELECT min(c) from example)
```

**EDIT:** if there's more then 1 records the answer the condition, then you need to decide which one you wanna pick.

```
SELECT * FROM example 
WHERE c = (SELECT min(c) from example)
ORDER BY d 
LIMIT 1
```

This will take the one with the smallest `d` value.

To take the biggest, add `DESC` after the order by d in the query.

Comment: Maybe handle the case where there is more than 1 row with the min value?

Comment: What to do if there is more than one row with '1.99'?

Comment: @frgtv10 if there is more then one, which one of them you want?

Comment: @sagi the lowest value of `d` in case if more than one row with the same `c` value (1.99)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subquery:

```
select e.*
    from (select min(c) as c from example) x 
    join example e 
    on x.c = e.c;
```

Comment: What to do if there is more than one row with '1.99'?

Comment: in this example it will return more than one row. It depends on what is required. One could return minimum/maximum/random value then... or concat them and return all.